# Function name in comment

Tags: go

Why do Go programmers put the name of the function as the first word of the function comment? This is a technical question please not a religious one.

As an example

```
// addOptions adds options s to opt
func addOptions(s string, opt interface{}) (string, error) {
....
```

Dose this not violate the SPOT (Single Point Of Truth) principle?

I am asking because I am sure there is a very good reason.

That is how it is done in 'The GO Programming Language' (Alan A. A. Donovan and Brian W. Kernighan). Also it was done like that in 'The C Programming Language' (Dennis M. Ritchie and Brian W. Kernighan) back in 1988. If it has lasted this long it seems there must be a good reason?

The SPOT  principle is attributed to Kernighan by Eric S. Raymond in 'The Art of UNIX Programming'.

Comment: It's recommended and discussed here: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#commentary

Comment: Correct. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR it makes grepping easier.

Quoting from https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#commentary referred to by @twotwotwo:

> Doc comments work best as complete sentences, which allow a wide
>   variety of automated presentations. The first sentence should be a
>   one-sentence summary that starts with the name being declared.
>
> ...
>
> If the name always begins the comment, the output of godoc can
>   usefully be run through grep. Imagine you couldn't remember the name
>   "Compile" but were looking for the parsing function for regular
>   expressions, so you ran the command,

```
$ godoc regexp | grep parse
```

> If all the doc comments in the package
>   began, "This function...", grep wouldn't help you remember the name.
>   But because the package starts each doc comment with the name, you'd
>   see something like this, which recalls the word you're looking for.

```
$ godoc regexp | grep parse
    Compile parses a regular expression and returns, if successful, a Regexp
    parsed. It simplifies safe initialization of global variables holding
    cannot be parsed. It simplifies safe initialization of global variables $
```

Comment: `golint` can also aid with checking documentation style.